# Is there an MCU czar or architect for VFX and stunts?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, behind-the-scenes, special-effects

It is well-known that Kevin Feige serves as the mastermind of the MCU, being  largely given credit for the immense success of the MCU.   He has wide-ranging responsible for the cohesion of all the films to comprise the MCU, and one assumes that be has final approval over all plot points and scripts.

These films are stunt- and especially VFX-heavy, employing many companies and hundreds of people to realize their effects visions for each film.   This is beyond the scope and likely the skill of any individual film director.  While there are some differing "looks" between films, there is also a degree of consistency and minimum quality expectations.

**Is there an architect, czar, or group at Marvel Studios responsible for maintaining consistency and quality in VFX and stunts across all the films?   Who are they?**

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there is any one person who fulfills this role but it seems like both [Ryan Meinerding](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2016096/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr281) and [Charlie Wen](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2657932/) would take that role as they have been labelled as Heads of Visual Development at Marvel Studios. According to IMDb:

> Ryan Meinerding is the Head of Visual Development at Marvel Studios. He has been with Marvel Studios since the early days of 'Iron Man,' helping to design the look and feel of the Marvel Cinematic Universe.

> Pioneer of Visual Storytelling for over two decades for the entertainment industry's largest franchises, including 4 worldwide top 10 Films and triple A games. Charlie's unrivaled creative leadership in story, character, and world creation has culminated in global smash hits such as Marvel's The Avengers, Guardians of the Galaxy, League of Legends, and God of War. He is most known for co-founding and heading Marvel's Visual Development, and was accountable for designing the look and feel of the Marvel Cinematic Universe since Thor in 2008.
>
> [...]
>
> By 2009 Charlie was invited by Marvel Studios, where he founded and headed Marvel's Visual Development department with Ryan Meinerding. As a department co-head, Charlie was responsible for designing and integrating the look and feel of Marvel's innumerable iconic heroes and villains from divergent realms into one cohesive cinematic universe. He was also in charge of inspiring future scripts through the visual storytelling of keyframes, art-directing the costume department and visual effects houses. His films include Thor, Captain America: the First Avenger, Marvel's The Avengers, Iron Man 3, Thor: the Dark World, The Guardians of the Galaxy, Captain America: Winter Soldier, Avengers: Age of Ultron, Ant-Man, and early art-direction of Black Panther.